# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such error:

> index.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
>   JSON at position 0

index.js(action):

```
import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData (day) {
    return async (dispatch) => {dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day });
    const response = await fetch(`api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`); 
    const data = (await response.json()).body; 
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data });
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data }); 
    } 
}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Based on the error it seems that your API doesn't return a valid JSON.

Comment: Please do not blank out your question once it is answered. One of the points of StackOverflow is to help *others* who may have the *same* question.

Comment: Too bad this has been closed... I think your issue is that you're not specifying the URL in your fetch call correctly. `api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}` is not an absolute URL, so it'll be trying to fetch from _your server_. Add an `//` before it or be explicit with a protocol, like: `https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the body.

```
const data = (await response.json());
```

Here's what I usually do:

```
const callAPI = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
fetch(url, options)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => resolve(res))
.catch(err => reject(err))
)
```

---

```
import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData (day) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day });
    const response = await fetch(`api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`); 
    const data = await response.json(); 
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data });
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data }); 
    } 
}
```

If you still get error, please open inspect window, go to network tab and share the screenshot of that API call.

Comment: ok, let me write another answer, please confirm that your API is working well on Postman